# Is it possible to pass custom request headers in casper.base64encode()?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, phantomjs, casperjs

The signature for casper.base64encode is given as:

```
base64encode(String url [, String method, Object data])
```

... and the docs give examples of how to pass form values using the `data` argument.  But is it possible to pass header strings?  In my case, I need to pass `Authentication` possibly `Accept` strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use `base64encode()`, because it doesn't support headers in any way. The underlying `__utils__.sendAJAX()` only supports the "Content-Type" request header. You can implement your own. Here is a step in the right direction by copying the necessary functions from the [clientutils module](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/clientutils.js) and adjusting them:

```
casper.base64encodeWithHeaders = function(url, method, data, headers) {
    return this.evaluate(function(url, method, data, headers){
        function getBinaryWithHeaders(url, method, data, headers) {
            try {
                return sendAjaxWithHeaders(url, method, data, false, {
                    overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined",
                    headers: headers
                });
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.name === "NETWORK_ERR" && e.code === 101) {
                    __utils__.log("getBinary(): Unfortunately, casperjs cannot make cross domain ajax requests", "warning");
                }
                __utils__.log("getBinary(): Error while fetching " + url + ": " + e, "error");
                return "";
            }
        };
        function sendAjaxWithHeaders(url, method, data, async, settings) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                dataString = "",
                dataList = [];
            method = method && method.toUpperCase() || "GET";
            var contentType = settings && settings.contentType || "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            xhr.open(method, url, !!async);
            __utils__.log("sendAJAX(): Using HTTP method: '" + method + "'", "debug");
            if (settings && settings.overrideMimeType) {
                xhr.overrideMimeType(settings.overrideMimeType);
            }
            if (method === "POST") {
                if (typeof data === "object") {
                    for (var k in data) {
                        dataList.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k].toString()));
                    }
                    dataString = dataList.join('&');
                    __utils__.log("sendAJAX(): Using request data: '" + dataString + "'", "debug");
                } else if (typeof data === "string") {
                    dataString = data;
                }
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
            }
            if (settings && settings.headers) {
                for(var header in settings.headers) {
                    if (settings.headers.hasOwnProperty(header)) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, settings.headers[header]);
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.send(method === "POST" ? dataString : null);
            return xhr.responseText;
        }

        return __utils__.encode(getBinaryWithHeaders(url, method, data, headers))
    }, url, method, data, headers);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var response = this.base64encodeWithHeaders("http://example.com", "GET", null, {
        "Accept": "text/plain",
        "Authentication": "let me in!"
    });
    this.echo(response);
});
```